# How to get all Jenkins job details for last 7 days and send that data over mail

Tags: email, powershell, jenkins, superblock, hudson

I am new on Jenkins and I wants powershell script to get the details of all jobs of Jenkins for last 15 days. I will send that details of Jenkin's jobs over mail to my Manager. I will be very thankful if any one resolve my Query.

I have tried below script.

```
 Hour=24;.  Minute=60;.   Second=60; oneDayInSecond=hourminutesecond;.  sevenDayInSecond=hourminutesecond*7;.  now=Calendar.instance;.  List=[];.  Println("${now.time}");

checkNewProjects(Hudson.instance.items). 

def checkNewProjects(items).  { For (items in items) {   last_build = items.lastbuild //or item.getlastbuild().    If (last_build) {.  build_time = last_build.timestamp.  If (now.time.time/1000-build_time.time.time/1000<sevenDayInSecond) {.  item.save().  Println(item.name).  Println("\t\tlast build was built in less than 7 days");      Println("\t\tlast built was at ${build_time.time); . list<< item; }.  }.  }. }.
```

Comment: Based on below question I have created the script that I posted in this question **https://stackoverflow.com/q/34797048/17772953**.

Comment: How can I send the output which I get over mail from Jenkins script console section.

Comment: I also installed global build stats plugin. From here also I am getting the details of all Jenkins job but still having the same problem that how can send the output of global build stats as attachment over mail to my Manager. –

Comment: I need help in one step that how can I send the output of global build stats data output as attachment over mail to my manager. Please help me in resolving this query

Comment: Can anyone please resolve this query.

Comment: Can anyone please resolve this query.

Comment: Can anyone please resolve this query